# How to filter a map field array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array of items that i map to get a result

```
 var items = $.grep($.selections);
```

in which items looks as follows:

```
0: {ID: "310882", Type: "W", Total: 10}
1: {ID: "31094", Type: "W",  Total: 10}
2: {ID: "307969", Type: "W",  Total: 10}
3: {ID: "311951", Type: "W",Total: 10}
4: {ID: "ItemCover_1611315351331", Type: "F", Total: 5, AmountDue:55}
```

so what i wanted to do was to get all of the Totals which i can as follows

```
var AllTotal=items.map(x => x.Total);
```

which gives me the bellow result

```
0: 10
1: 10
2: 10
3: 10
4: 5
```

the question i have if you notice this item in the array

```
4: {ID: "ItemCover_1611315351331", Type: "F", Total: 5, AmountDue:55}
```

it has an ID: starting with "ItemCover" and it has AmountDue of 55

when i have an item of such nature how can i filter the Total of 5 out and replace it with the Amount Due so that it should now look like this

```
var AllTotal
   0: 10
    1: 10
    2: 10
    3: 10
    4: 55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest version assuming you want AmountDue if it exists

```js
const arr = [{ID: "310882", Type: "W", Total: 10},
 {ID: "31094", Type: "W",  Total: 10},
 {ID: "307969", Type: "W",  Total: 10},
 {ID: "311951", Type: "W",Total: 10},
 {ID: "ItemCover_1611315351331", Type: "F", Total: 5, AmountDue:55}];

 const newArr = arr.map(({Total,AmountDue}) => AmountDue || Total)

 console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `ID` property starts with 'ItemCover', get the value of `AmountDue` property, otherwise, get the value of the `Total` property

```
items.map(x => x.ID.startsWith('ItemCover_') ? x.AmountDue : x.Total)
```

You can read more info on [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)